# My Scene bpy.types.Panel appears on all tabs

Tags: python, properties, panel

I created a simple `bpy.types.Panel` to allow modification of custom scene properties, wanting it to appear only on the Scene property tab, and thus created it like this:

```
class MK8PanelSceneCourse(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Mario Kart 8 Course"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_mk8course"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
```

This works fine, and the panel appears on the scene property tab as expected:

[image: Scene tab]

However, I noticed it also appears on every other tab. Here's an example with the World tab, where it's even the World name textbox:

[image: World tab]

How can I make it appear only on the scene tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I forgot to set up the `bl_context` member of my panel. Sadly, [the documentation is not very clear about the possible values](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_context) (it would be great it if someone could list them and link it in a comment).

For the scene tab, the panel code would be:

```
class MK8PanelSceneCourse(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Mario Kart 8 Course"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_mk8course"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "scene"
```

Comment: Mouse over icons on top of properties panel. Lowercase versions of https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.SpaceProperties.html#bpy.types.SpaceProperties.context

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks, I didn't know it would map exactly to the tooltips =)